# Error in cursor illegal state exception

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm getting this error.

```
09-05 16:17:27.460: E/CursorWindow(29553): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 8 columns.
09-05 16:17:27.465: E/AndroidRuntime(29553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 16:17:27.465: E/AndroidRuntime(29553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nesv.landstar/com.nesv.landstar.LandstarPage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with my code. Here it is:

```
Cursor c = null;

        try
        {
            c = landstarDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DriverShipment", null);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Error selecting table", "Error selecting table");
        }

 if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
         c.moveToFirst();
         do {
             Log.i("cctid:", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid")));
             if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid")) == cctid)
             {
                 isRecorded = true;
                 shipmentId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid"));
                 origin = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("origin"));
                 destination = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("destination"));
                 protectTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("protect_time"));
                 readyTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ready_time"));
                 etat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("eta"));

                 if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("isAccepted")) == "1")
                 {
                     isAccepted = true;
                 }
             }
         }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
            c.close();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what does this Log.i("cctid:", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid"))); give you? Also remove c.moveToFirst() from whithin the if condition..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`column -1` tells you that there is no column `cctid`, and `getColumnIndex` returns -1.

Also

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid")) == cctid
```

Will not work. Strings are compared using the `equals` method.

I suggest you post your table creation Query so we can see why the column is not there.

Comment: Somewhat pointed the issue that causes my error. But the real error is that I'm looking for the wrong column name that is why it returns -1. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**You have call** `c.moveToFirst();` **two times**

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
         c.moveToFirst(); // Remove this one
```

Comment: which, while it is useless, is not a problem at all. it will go to the first position, and then again go to the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop as below:

```
if (c.getCount > 0) {
     c.moveToFirst();
     do {
         Log.i("cctid:", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid")));
         if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid")) == cctid)
         {
             isRecorded = true;
             shipmentId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cctid"));
             origin = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("origin"));
             destination = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("destination"));
             protectTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("protect_time"));
             readyTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ready_time"));
             etat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("eta"));

             if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("isAccepted")) == "1")
             {
                 isAccepted = true;
             }
         }
     }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
```